# Alternative to GROUP BY to optimize SQL call

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

I have the following SQL statement that is VERY slow. It varies from 600-800ms!

I'm looking for possible ways to optimize it, but not sure exactly the best route. My database is fairly big, with the `entries` table having 400,000 rows and the `devices` table having 90,000 rows.

---

***SQL Statement***

```
SELECT devices.manufacturer, COUNT(devices.manufacturer) AS device_count 
FROM entries 
   JOIN devices ON entries.device_id=devices.id 
WHERE waypoint_id IN (1,2,3,5) 
  AND entries.updated_at >= '2013-06-20 21:01:40 -0400' 
  AND entries.updated_at <= '2013-06-27 21:01:40 -0400'
  GROUP BY devices.manufacturer;
```

Is this SQL statement slow because I'm running it on poor hardware, or because the statement is bad, or have I not structured the table correctly? Any thoughts would be appreciated!

---

***Goal of Statement***

Get a list of all the device manufacturers, and the associated count of how many times that manufacturer showed up in the entries table.

---

***Table Structure***

**Devices**

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
mac_address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
user_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
created_at datetime NOT NULL,
updated_at datetime NOT NULL,
manufacturer varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE KEY mac_address (mac_address),
KEY manufacturer (manufacturer)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=839310 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**Entries**

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
device_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
created_at datetime NOT NULL,
updated_at datetime NOT NULL,
waypoint_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
unsure tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY device_index (device_id)
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3389538 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

Also– I have been looking into alternate databases. Considering this database is going to need very fast read/writes in the future, would something like Redis be of use?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables?

Comment: On the Entries table I have a PK on the id and an index on the device_id. On the Devices table, I have a PK on the id and an index on manufacturer and mac_address

Comment: 600-800ms is slow?   am I missing something?

Comment: If you look at the bottom of my post, where I detail the tables, the indexes are listed.

Comment: @MK 600-800ms might not seem slow.. but when you change the date range to over a month, the call slows down to ~2 seconds. If you remove the group by it is considerably faster (~200ms). I'm wondering if I should pull it out with MySQL and then sort with ruby.

Comment: Adding an index on the dates used is probably the biggest time saver, also your example has no GROUP BY.

Comment: Is MySQL local?  What kind of hard drive?  I have no experience with MySQL and am not sure if you are querying locally or over the network, but in my experience with things like Oracle, no query completes under 500ms ever.

Comment: How many rows do you have in these two tables?

Comment: Without an index on entries.updated_at, a full scan of the entries table will be necessary. What is `logs` referring to?

Comment: @Glenn logs was a mis-type. It was supposed to be entries

Comment: @MathieuRodic About 400K rows in entries, and 80K rows in devices

Comment: @Glenn interesting note on the entries.updated_at index. Didn't realize it would scan the whole thing. I'll try indexing it now to see how that works. However, I am nervous because the updated_at column is updating quite often (who would thought! ha). So, I hope that doesn't affect write performance.

Comment: @BrianW It really is going to depend on the profile of the data. If the date ranges being queried are going to be more than say, 5% or 10% of the all records in the table, then the index probably wouldn't be worth it. And yes, if entries are always updated, then there is extra indexing cost to weigh against query performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query would run faster if you added a multiple-column index on `entries(waypoint_id, updated_at)`.

Also, you query would look better like this:

```
SELECT
    devices.manufacturer,
    COUNT(devices.manufacturer) AS device_count 
FROM
    entries
JOIN
    devices ON devices.id = entries.device_id
WHERE
    entries.waypoint_id IN (1,2,3,5)
AND
    entries.updated_at BETWEEN '2013-06-20 21:01:40 -0400' AND '2013-06-27 21:01:40 -0400'
GROUP BY
    devices.device_id
```

P.S.: wouldn't it be a good thing to explicitely declare `device_id` as a foreign key?

Comment: @BrianW No. BTW, this is true under any DBMS, not just MySQL.

Comment: @BrianW No, it is not the same as two indexes. A multi-part will need to match the prefix for a hit. So, if the index is on "A,B" then it won't generally be of use if you want to search on "B".  The suggestion is probably that with a multi-part index you may be able to get all the info from an index scan without even bothering to go to the table. But this won't be of any use if `waypoint_id` is of low cardinality.

Comment: Thanks– was just reading about the multi column indexes. Good to know for the future. Also– after adding the indexes the time dropped from ~650 to ~420.

Comment: @BrianW hum, 420ms is still a lot... are you sure you added ONE multiple-columns index, and not TWO separate indexes on each of the two columns? If not, try this index instead: `entries(updated_at, waypoint_id)` (MySQL sometimes works in mysterious ways...)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an index on `Entries {waypoint_id, updated_at}`. This should satisfy the:

```
WHERE waypoint_id IN (1,2,3,5) 
  AND entries.updated_at >= '2013-06-20 21:01:40 -0400' 
  AND entries.updated_at <= '2013-06-27 21:01:40 -0400';
```

Depending on actual cardinalities, you may or may not want to reverse the order of fields in this composite index.

Alternatively, create a [covering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) index on `Entries {waypoint_id, updated_at, device_id}`, to avoid accessing the `Entries` table altogether.

---

On top of that, consider creating an index on `Devices {id, manufacturer}`. Hopefully, MySQL will be smart enough to use it to satisfy both JOIN and aggregation without even accessing the `Devices` table.